# How to convert huge file with huge number of rows from long to wide format in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, reshape, tidyr

I have a dataframe `ACC` which looks like following: The dataframe shows miRNA and Target interactions:

ACC:

```
  miRNAs        Targets
MIMAT0000075    HIF1A
MIMAT0000449    CXCR4
MIMAT0000421    CYP7A1
MIMAT0000279    STAT5A
MIMAT0000076    RASGRP1
```

I converted the above long format to wider format using `mutate` and `pivot_wider`. I used the following snippet for the conversion: If there is interaction it will be `1` else `0`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

validated_targets <- ACC %>%
  mutate(n = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = miRNAs, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
```

The output looks like below:

[image]

Help needed:

The above dataframe is just a small example. I have a dataframe with 400639 rows and two columns. The dimension of my original data is below:

```
dim(originaldata)
[1] 400639      2
```

I'm not able to convert my original data from long to wider format in `Rstudio`. Can anyone please tell me how to convert such huge file from long to wider format like the output given above?

thanq

Comment: Try [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html).

Comment: @JBGruber If you don't mind could you please give me an example.

Comment: What is your reason for wanting it wide?

Comment: @Kel that is needed for some of my work

Comment: There might be a better way to achieve what you want which will save you having to make it wide.

Comment: But for some of my work, I need the table like the above example output. There is no other way. This is what I need.

Comment: From the [tidyr::pivot vignette](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) - "It’s relatively rare to need pivot_wider() to make tidy data, but it’s often useful for creating summary tables for presentation, or data in a format needed by other tools." You may get a more helpful response if you can say why you need it in a wide format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the `data.table` equivalent to `pivot_wider` - `dcast`:

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

dt_wide <- dt %>%
  mutate(n = 1) %>% 
  dcast(Targets ~ miRNAs, value.var = "n", fill = 0)

dt_wide
#>   Targets MIMAT0000075 MIMAT0000076 MIMAT0000279 MIMAT0000421 MIMAT0000449
#> 1   CXCR4            0            0            0            0            1
#> 2  CYP7A1            0            0            0            1            0
#> 3   HIF1A            1            0            0            0            0
#> 4 RASGRP1            0            1            0            0            0
#> 5  STAT5A            0            0            1            0            0
```

### data

```r
dt <- fread("miRNAs        Targets
MIMAT0000075    HIF1A
MIMAT0000449    CXCR4
MIMAT0000421    CYP7A1
MIMAT0000279    STAT5A
MIMAT0000076    RASGRP1")


dt
#>          miRNAs Targets
#> 1: MIMAT0000075   HIF1A
#> 2: MIMAT0000449   CXCR4
#> 3: MIMAT0000421  CYP7A1
#> 4: MIMAT0000279  STAT5A
#> 5: MIMAT0000076 RASGRP1
```

### benchmarking

The `data.table` function is supposed to be quicker. So let's try how much of a difference this makes in this case and with data that is the same size as the data described in the question:

```r
# simulate data
dt_big <- data.table(
  miRNAs = sample(dt$miRNAs, 400639, replace = TRUE),
  Targets = sample(dt$Targets, 400639, replace = TRUE)
)

# create mock functions for easier benchmarking
dt_dcast <- function(x) {
  dt %>%
    mutate(n = 1) %>% 
    dcast(Targets ~ miRNAs, value.var = "n", fill = 0)
}

tidyr_pivot_wider <- function(variables) {
  dt %>%
    mutate(n = 1) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = miRNAs, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
}

bench::mark(
  dt_dcast(dt_big),
  tidyr_pivot_wider(dt_big),
  check = FALSE
)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   expression                     min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>                <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 dt_dcast(dt_big)             1.8ms      2ms      462.     973KB     10.5
#> 2 tidyr_pivot_wider(dt_big)   4.02ms   4.52ms      218.     826KB     13.5
```

As you can see, `data.table` takes less than half the time to complete the task. However, neither function really takes long on that size of a dataset and I'm a little surprised you are having problems with `pivot_wider` in the first place.

Comment: But I would like to know Will I get the output quickly, Or will take huge time for conversion. Asking this because with "pivot_wider" I also get the same output, but it is taking hours of time and didn't get required output with the huge input file.

Comment: I was about to add this to the answer. `data.table` is usually fast than `dplyr`/`tidyr`.

Comment: I'm really surprised though that you weren't able to use `pivot_wider` on your data. Maybe it would make sense to describe how exactly `R` failed to perform the task.

Comment: Wow this is awesome. I got the required output with "data.table" in few mins, but the problem with dplyr/tidyr and using "pivot_wider" is its been already more than hour for conversion, but it is still running. But anyways "data.table" is super fast as you said.

Comment: Great! One stupid question though: Have you checked if either `miRNAs` or `Targets` is a factor? I imagine that would increase the time for computation by a lot.

Comment: Yes, it is factor.

Comment: The I assumethis should be pretty quick as well: `dt %>%
    mutate(n = 1) %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = miRNAs, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))`